# Android : IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I am working on Fragment transactions. I start with `homepage_fragment` from the main activity and go to the `second fragment`, but when coming back to the 'homepage_fragment', I am getting an error (put below). I want to get back to same instance of the `homepage_fragment` and not a new instance.

The `change_fragment` method is called when moving to `second fragment` and `change_fragment2` is called when moving the other way.

```
Fragment homepage_fragment = new HomePageFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_main, homepage_fragment,"homepage_fragment").commit();
```

These are the interface methods implemented in the main activity.

```
@Override
public void change_fragment(){
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    String tag = "homepage_fragment";
    Fragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main,  newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void change_fragment2() {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //String tag1 = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName();
    String tag1 = "second_fragment";
    int lastFragCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() -1;
    String fragName= getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(lastFragCount).getName();
    Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragName);
    ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, newFragment , tag1);
    ft.addToBackStack(tag1);
    ft.commit();
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.user.popupwindowdemo, PID: 10309
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment HomePageFragment{2141e52a #0 id=0x7f0c006f homepage_fragment}: was homepage_fragment now second_fragment
```

Since, the tag name passed in the `replace` method is to tag the current fragment, I dont think I am changing tag names of any fragments here. So, they should remain the same.

When debugging, the object reference returned by `findFragmentByTag()` is correct, but it returns the error after the next statement. I am not able to understand clearly what's going wrong here. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: This seems like a strange navigational flow. Normally you would use `add()` instead of `replace()`; then after you add a second `Fragment` to the back stack, you would just call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` to return to the previous `Fragment`. Or if you would like to swap the fragments out; you can just call `replace()` without adding the `Fragment` to the back stack.

Comment: @Bryan It works, I only started learning this recently and did not know about `popBackStack()`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually creating a new `Fragment`. This method:

```
Fragment newFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragName);
```

Is just finding the last `Fragment` in the back stack, then you are trying to replace that `Fragment` with itself.

The normal method to create a back stack of fragments would be to add a fragment like so:

```
@Override
public void addFragment(String tag, Fragment fragment) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.activity_main, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(tag)
            .commit();
}
```

Then you can just remove the last `Fragment` with:

```
@Override
public void removeFragment() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: With `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragName);`, I get the homepage_fragment which is what is needed and once I have the reference, I simply replace the  current fragment. Isn't that what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @ashwinx Yes, but you do not need a reference to the previous fragment, you can just replace or add the `Fragment` based on the id of the layout element.